# Owl-carousel isn't responsive

Tags: responsive-design, drupal-7, owl-carousel

I'm having trouble making OC2 responsive. I'm running:
Drupal 7.32, Owl 7.x-2.x-dev, Jquery 1.10.

I defined a custom carousel setting with these values:

Responsive 1
Width 0; Items 1

Responsive 2
Width 480; Items 2

Responsive 3
Width: 768, Items 3

Oddly, the owlcarousel section of jQuery.extend statement lacks the above responsive settings, but has all the other owlcarousel settings.

The slider is set to autoplay. The slider works but always displays 3 items (which is what the first Items value is set to at the top of the OC configuration page. I have rebuilt the view and cleared caches multiple times.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

When using the 2.x branch make sure you clear your cache after updating the responsive variables in the admin section.